# Magento2: Issue with IntlDateFormatter breaking page load

Tags: php, datetime, magento, nginx, magento2

Across multiple pages on my Magento installation I'm getting errors like this:

[image]

So it seems to be breaking the page load and echoing out:

`object(IntlDateFormatter)#2176 (0) { }`

I'm running 7.1, have `php7.1-intl` installed and showing up in phpinfo. The `date.timezone` setting is set to UTC.

Nothing is coming up in my php or nginx log and nothing seems to be in any of the Magento logs.

It seems to be happening on more and more pages, currently it's showing up on the admin index, a single attribute when trying to edit and the accounts page of the M2E Pro extension.

Any help is greatly appreciated as I'm at a total loss on this one.

Answer (score 0):

Solved, a var_dump() had been put in:

`./vendor/magento/framework/Stdlib/DateTime/Timezone.php`

If anyone is looking for a similar issue, I grepped over the whole Magento code base with:

`grep -nr 'var_dump(' --exclude='*Large*' ./`

And found it through looking through those results.